FEM weak formulation - integration by parts on double spatial derivative term involving three variables
So I'm trying to derive a model using FEM to reduce the order of the spatial derivatives in my beam mechanical PDE system. After taking the weak formulation I get the following term:
$\int_{0}^{L}(-(A_1+A_2)\sin (2 \theta )\frac{\mathrm{d^2} y}{\mathrm{d} s^2}v) ds$
Where $L$ is the length of the rod/beam, $A_1$ and $A_2$ stiffness constants, $\theta$ the angle and depends on $s, y$ is vertical displacement and depends on $s, v$ is the test function used in FEM and also depends on $s$. The bit which is confusing me is that this is a integral involving three variables and I'm not sure the correct way to use integration by parts to lower the double derivative in space as is needed in the weak formulation for FEM. TIA
